# Asp.Net MVC Virtual Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

Is there such a thing?

I have two projects within the same solution.

When I run the solution within Visual Studio two separate instances of localhost are launched.

project foo is available at http://localhost:3091

and

project bar is available at http://localhost:3094

I would like to have access to project bar within foo for example: http://localhost:3091/bar/

From my research on areas it seems like I would have to recreate the bar project as an area within the foo project.

Is there a way to do this for example with a *Virtual* Area without having to recreate within an area?

Is this possible and, if not, what is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: The correct way is to use an area.  What would a "virtual area" even mean?

Comment: @Kirk - a way to map a project to an area without having to recreate the project within an area - if such a facility exists??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are needing to do is host these web projects in local IIS.  You need to have http://localhost/proj1 and http://localhost/proj2 and http://localhost/proj1/bar.  Using areas needs to come down to an architecture decision.  It sounds like perhaps keepthing these two projects would be desired.  Just run them under local IIS, change the properties page in each project to reflect that.

To directly address your question, No.  I am not aware of anything that exists and not aware of any plans for such a thing to exist.